Dimension of variety of an irred poly in $\mathbb{A}^n$

Suppose $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{A}^n$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. Show $\dim Z(f) = n-1$ [Hint: Use Hilbert Nullstellensatz]

I am using the definition that the dimension of $X$ is the minimum tangent space dimension. I would like to know how to prove this statement using Hilbert Nullstellensatz?
Here is my Nullstellensatz-free solution:
The statement is equivalent to there being a point $q$ such that $\nabla f |_q\neq 0$. Suppose not. If $p=0$, we're done as $f$ is constant otherwise $f$ is a function of $(X_1^p,\dots,X_n^p)$, thus $f$ is a $p$th power (Sophomore rule) so reducible.

Your proof doesn't seem valid to me: the statement is only equivalent to there being a point $q \in Z(f)$ such that $\nabla f |_q \ne 0$, from whose negation you cannot immediately conclude that $f$ is a constant (it is of course the constant $0$ restricted to $Z(f)$).
